# Filter list to remove non numeric items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following controller method to grab the id's of all selected items in my Grid.Mvc, however I am noticing I am getting not only the id's of the selected items, but also a `"false"` for each row, which obviously I don't want.

I have put together the following code smell to leave me with just the id's so that I can do my thing however is there a better way of doing this, at the very least is there a way of filtering out the non numeric list items rather than my existing method which is hardcoding true/false:

```
//POST
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost(FormCollection collection)
{
    var selectedIds = collection.GetValues("selectedAddressesIds");
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    myList = selectedIds.ToList();
    myList.RemoveAll(x => (x == "false") || (x == "true")); 

    if (myList != null )
    {
        foreach (var id in myList)
        {
            // do what you want with the selected id.
        }
    }  

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I can smell something.

Comment: @Invent-Animate *"I am noticing I am getting not only the id's of the selected items, but also a "false" for each row, which obviously I don't want."* indicates that the code does not work *as intended* which makes it off-topic for Code Review

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I just didn't read that as the main point of this thread.

Comment: Best guess is you using `CheckBoxFor()` which generates an associated hidden input with a `value="False"` so that you can bind to your model (since unchecked boxes do not post a value), but your using `FormCollection` (why would you use that instead of binding to your model?)

Comment: Because im using Grid.Mvc, binding a model seems to be proving difficult with the state of the check box

Comment: @SelectDistinct,  Show how you are generating the checkbox - there is no need for this kind of hack

Comment: I have a bool on my view model and have added it to my grid like so columns.Add(a => a.IsChecked).Titled("Checked").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("selectedAddressesIds", false, new { value = o.EmailId }));

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Grid.MVC` and whether you can post back to a model, but you can easily solve this using manual html for the checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="selectedAddressesIds" value="@o.EmailId">` and then post back to `public ActionResult IndexPost(int[] selectedAddressesIds)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer just the question about filtering, you could retrieve just the numeric values using one of these options:

```
var exampleList = new List<string>{"1", "2", "rubbish", "3", "trash", "4.5"};

int dummyInt; // just because you need an out param of type int

// filteredInts will contain {1, 2, 3}
var filteredInts = exampleList.Where(item => int.TryParse(item, out dummyInt));

double dummyDouble; // just because you need an out param of type double

// filteredDoubles will contain {1, 2, 3, 4.5}
var filterdDoubles = exampleList.Where(item => double.TryParse(item, out dummyDouble));
```

Ofcourse, if you just want to filter the original list, you can use the complementary logic for `RemoveAll()`:

```
// If you only want int values:
myList.RemoveAll(item => ! int.TryParse(item, out dummyDouble));

// ..or want to also keep double values:
myList.RemoveAll(item => ! double.TryParse(item, out dummyDouble));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the GetValues("selectedAddressesIds") method is returning things other than the IDs of the selected addresses, that is the problem that you should fix rather than tweaking the results list.

Without seeing where the results come from I'm not sure why you have values of "true" and "false" in this list, but if it is for every entry then it shouldn't be too hard to find if you look at where the selectedAddressesIds collection is populated.

To answer the title question more directly, though, if you merely want to avoid hard-coding "true" and "false" you can try to parse to int and discard any that don't parse:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
int dummy;  // because TryParse takes an out parameter
myList.RemoveAll(x => !int.TryParse(x, out dummy));
```

But, I'd encourage you to find the root cause of the invalid values.

Comment: I understand your point, for now this will have to be a TODO as I have a number of more pressing things to complete, I am aware this is not the final solution and is a 'hack' but it will have to do for now.